# SSIS Data Flow data access mode - what's the point of 'table or view' vs fast load?

Tags: ssis

Using the SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio, I do a lot of flat file to OLE DB destination data flows to import data to my SQL Server tables.  Under "Data access mode" in in the OLE DB destination editor, it defaults to "table or view" rather than "table or view - fast load".  What is the difference; the only discernible difference I can perceive is that the fast load transfers the data much faster.

Answer (score 15):

The OLE DB Destination Component's Data Access Modes comes in two flavors - fast and non-fast.

Fast, either "table or view - fast load" or "table or view name variable - fast load" means that data will be loaded in a set-based fashion.

Slow - either the "table or view" or "table or view name variable" will result in SSIS issuing singleton insert statements to the database. If you're loading 10, 100, maybe even 10000 rows, there's probably little appreciable performance difference between the two methods. However, at some point you're going to saturate your SQL Server instance with all these piddly little requests. Additionally, you're going to abuse the heck out of your transaction log.

Why would you ever want the non-fast methods? Bad data. If I sent in 10000 rows of data and the 9999th row had a date of 2015-02-29, you would have 10k atomic inserts and commits/rollbacks. If I was using the Fast method, that entire batch of 10k rows will either all save or none of them. And if you want to know which row(s) errored out, the lowest level of granularity you will have is 10k rows.

Now, there are approaches to getting as much data loaded as fast as possible and still handle dirty data. It's a [cascading failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466699/181965) approach and it looks something like

[image: cascading failure insert]

The idea is that you find the right size to insert as much as possible in one shot but if you get bad data, you're going to try resaving the data in successively smaller batches to get to the bad rows. Here I started with a Maximum insert commit size (FastLoadMaxInsertCommit) of 10000. On the Error Row disposition, I change it to `Redirect Row` from `Fail Component`.

The next destination is the same as above but here I attempt a fast load and save it in batches of 100 rows. Again, test or make some pretense of coming up with a reasonable size. This will result in 100 batches of 100 rows sent because we know *somewhere* in there, there is at least one row that violated the integrity constraints for the table.

I then add a third component to the mix, this time I save in batches of 1. Or you can just change the table access mode away from the Fast Load version because it'll yield the same result. We will save each row individually and that will enable us to do "something" with the single bad row(s).

Finally, I have a failsafe destination. Maybe it's the "same" table as the intended destination but all the columns are declared as `nvarchar(4000) NULL`. Whatever ends up at that table needs to be researched and cleaned/discarded or whatever your bad data resolution process is. Others dump to a flat file but really, whatever makes sense for how you want to track bad data works.

Answer (score 5):

Fast Load is well documented under [FAST LOAD options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> - Keep identity values from the imported data file or use unique values assigned by SQL Server.
> - Retain a null value during the bulk load operation.
> - Check constraints on the target table or view during the bulk import operation.
> - Acquire a table-level lock for the duration of the bulk load operation.
>   Specify the number of rows in the batch and the commit size.

---

> What is the difference; the only discernible difference I can perceive is that the fast load transfers the data much faster.

Under the hood, `table or view` will use individual SQL Command for every row to insert vs `table or view - with fast load` will use the BULK INSERT command.

If you see above options that are available in [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) e.g. `number of rows in the batch`  = `ROWS_PER_BATCH` and  `commit size` = `BATCHSIZE`

Another scenario will be ..

The default Maximum Insert Commit Size (2147483647) is too high. So for e.g. you are inserting 500K rows and due to PK violation the batch fails. In this scenario, entire batch will fail when you use FAST LOAD option. You wont be able to get the error description as well.

This is where you can have `table or view` as destination Error output. So out of 500K, you use FAST LOAD as starting with an insert commit size of 5K. If 1 row in that batch fails, you will redirect those 5K batch to `table or view` load - which uses row by row insert ONLY for 5K rows and you can as well redirect the error of `table or view` to a flat file .. so that if any row fails the batch if 5K, you will be able to pinpoint what caused the failure.

The advantage of above method is that if none of the rows fails, then it will use BULK INSERT (fast load) for the entire batch.

SSIS aficionado [billinkc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181965/billinkc) [answered a similar question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466699/1387418).